# Could quantum vacuum fluctuations affect molecules of water somehow and make them evaporate or sublimate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

If we had a quantity of water in vacuum that stayed solid or liquid somehow, could quantum vacuum fluctuations affect molecules of water somehow and make them evaporate or sublimate?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, here is why.

The idea of quantum fluctuations in the vacuum applies only to objects (i.e., distance scales) far smaller than an atom, which leaves those fluctuations with no mechanism by which they can communicate themselves to objects the size of, say, water molecules.

Furthermore, those fluctuations have characteristic "lifetimes" that are far, far shorter than the timescales associated with molecular movements, so even if they could communicate themselves to molecules, they vanish before the molecule has any opportunity to measurably respond to them.

Finally, the dynamics of molecular movements have been the subject of extensive and thorough theoretical and experimental work for more than 150 years and for example the so-called *kinetic theory of gases* (which has no quantum mechanics in it) has been found to furnish an excellent description of the behavior of things like water molecules. If quantum effects on molecular vibrations were real, they would have been seen by now.

CAVEAT! this is true for "ordinary circumstances" where the molecules and atoms in question are not under extraordinary pressures and/or temperatures, as you would find in the center of stars for example. In those extraordinary circumstances, quantum mechanical effects (and special relativity too) must be taken into account.